# How do I pass data from the list view template to edit view template using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an `SPA` using angular and `ASP.NET Web API`. I use `ui-router` module. I have a list view displaying customers with an edit button through which I want to pass a `customerId` to the `editCustomerController.js` to be used to fetch the customer to edit from the web `API`. 
I can't seem to make heads on this.

*CustomerView.html*

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in vm.customers">
  <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.identificationNumber}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.surname}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.otherName}}</td>
  <td>
     <a ui-sref="customerEdit" ng-click="vm.setSelectedCustomerId(customer.id)">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
     </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

How do I pass the `customerId` to the `editCustomerController.js` from this template?

Comment: Why do you use `ui-sref="customerEdit"` together with `ng-click`? It seems to me that it should be either/or - either you want to navigate to a new state (`customreEdit`) *or* to do something in the current state and its controller with `setSelectedCustomerId`

Comment: I want to navigate to the edit view and pass the selected customer id to be used to fetch the customer to edit from web api@New Dev

Comment: You could pass the parameter directly with `ui-sref` (depending on your state definition), for example, like so: `ui-sref="customerEdit({ id: customer.id })"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue using ui-sref="customerEdit({ id: customer.id })" as pointed out by @New Dev. 
Changed the *CustomerView.html* edit link to

```
<td>
   <a data-ui-sref="customerEdit({ id: customer.id })">
     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
   </a>
</td>
```

*customerEdit state*

```
$stateProvider
     .state("customerEdit", {
         url: "/customers/edit/:id",
         templateUrl: "/editCustomerView.html",
         controller: "editCustomerController"
      })
```

*editCustomerController.js*

```
function editCustomerController($stateParams, customerResource) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.editableCustomer = {};
    vm.selectedCustomerId = $stateParams.id;

    customerResource.get({ id: vm.selectedCustomerId },
        function(data) {
            vm.editableCustomer = data;
            ...
        });
};
```